# Odd issue with std::map and thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

This isn't so much of a problem now as I've implemented my own collection but still a little curious on this one.

I've got a singleton which provides access to various common components, it holds instances of these components with thread ID's so each thread should (and does, I checked) have it's own instance of the component such as an Oracle database access library.

When running the system (which is a C++ library being called by a C# application) with multiple incoming requests everything seems to run fine for a while but then it crashes out with an *AccessViolation* exception.  Stepping through the debugger the problem appears to be when one thread finishes and clears out it's session information (held in a std::map object) the session information held in a separate collection instance for the other thread also appears to be cleared out.

Is this something anyone else has encountered or knows about?  I've tried having a look around but can't find anything about this kind of problem.

Cheers

Comment: "I've got a singleton..." Well that's the problem right there. :)

Comment: Honestly, I'm surprised that no-one said that sooner :)

Answer (score 2):

Standard C++ containers do not concern themselves with thread safety much. Your code sounds like it is modifying the map instance from two different threads or modifying the map in one thread and reading from it in another. That is obviously wrong. Use some locking primitives to synchronize the access between the threads.

Comment: That's what I thought initially, but checking the info in the debugger I can see that both maps are at seperate memory locations.  So where I have: (Thread 1 -> map a) and (Thread 2 -> map b) when thread 1 clears "map a" I end up with "map b" being cleared down as well?

Comment: @daz-fuller: If they are in fact separate `map`s, then you probably have a deeper issue. Go back to the debugger until you do understand the issue, or you might just be hidding the bug instead of fixing it.

Comment: @daz-fuller: What compiler are you using for the C++ code? What version?

Comment: @daz-fuller: Also, are you linking the C++ code with the right run time libraries? The threads supporting versions?

Comment: It's being built with MSVC (version 8, studio 2005) and GCC (3.4.5).  It's a statically linked library and it's being link to the multi-threaded versions.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a separate object for each thread, you might want to take a look at [`boost::thread_specific_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html).

Comment: I do frequently, unfortunately because of the nature of the project we're limited to the STL and anything we write ourselves :(

Comment: I'd suggest you look at the code for thread_specific_ptr and write it yourself then.

Answer (score 0):

How do you manage giving each thread its own session information? Somewhere under there you have classes managing the lifetimes of these objects, and this is where it appears to be going wrong.

Comment: There is a singleton which handles these items, when it's asked for, say, a debug logger it checks to see if one exists for that thread, if not then one is created.  That bit's working fine, the problem is with the thread specific instances created.  One specific type has a clear down method.  So "Thread A" has "Object A" with "Map A" and "Thread B" has "Object B" with "Map B", for some reason every once in a while calling the clear down method on "Object A" affects both "Map A" and "Map B"

Comment: So it checks in some kind of table. It then removes it from some kind of table when the thread has finished. That table is thus used by multiple threads. Also beware of iterators getting potentially invalidated.

Comment: If it was a problem with the static lookup table then I'd expect the wrong map to be cleared but not both.  Also I'd expect some of the wrong Objects properties to be modified but they're not, the correct object has it's modified?